# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating ' _this.setState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, typeerror

i'm a complete beginner to React Native and i'm trying to add items to flatlist using textinput. i keep constantly getting a TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.setState'). i have edited the code many times and tried to research what i can do, but it still is not working properly. could someone help me and tell me what i need to change? below is my code.
thank you in advance!

```
import React, { useState, setState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, Alert, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function FlatlistComponent({ }) {

    const array = [{title: 'ONE'}, {title: 'TWO'}];
    const [arrayHolder] = React.useState([]);
    const [textInputHolder] = React.useState('');

    const componentDidMount = () => {
        setState({ arrayHolder: [...array] })
    }

    const joinData = () => {
        array.push({ title : textInputHolder });
        this.setState({ arrayHolder: [...array] });
    }

    const FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                height: 1,
                width: "100%",
                backgroundColor: "#607D8B",
                }} />
        );
    }

    const GetItem = (item) => {
        Alert.alert(item);
    }


    return (

      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter Value Here"
          onChangeText={data => this.setState({ textInputHolder: data })}
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={joinData} activeOpacity={0.7} style={styles.button} >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Add Values To FlatList </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <FlatList
          data={arrayHolder}
          width='100%'
          extraData={arrayHolder}
          keyExtractor={(index) => index.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item} onPress={GetItem.bind(this, item.title)} > {item.title} </Text>}
        />
      </View>

    );
  }
```

Comment: In order to use this.setState you must work with class components, and in your example you're using a functional component which uses hooks in order to change the state.

Comment: You are mixing up class-based and function-based components. The `useState` hook returns the setter function too, and arrow functions don't have their own `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see you're trying to use functional components here. 
State variables can be rewritten like this

```
const [arrayHolder, setArrayHolder] = useState([]);
const [textInputHolder, setTextInputHolder] = useState('');
```

componentDidMount is used in class components and can be rewritten like this for functional components

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
useEffect(()=>{
  setArrayHolder(array)
}, [])
```

Function `joinData` can be re-written like this.

```
const joinData = () => {
        array.push({ title : textInputHolder });
        setArrayHolder(array)
    }
```

About the text not showing up. You're using `this.setState` in the `onChangeText` event. It is a functional component and `this` won't work in a functional component.`state` variables are declared and set using the `useState` hook in a  functional component.

You should rewrite the onChangeText event like this.

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Enter Value Here"
    onChangeText={data => setTextInputHolder(data)}
    style={styles.textInputStyle}
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
/>
```

I think this'll solve your problem

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: could you help me with another problem? when i write to the textinput and press the button, the text doesn't show. only empty white space. the code seems to work otherwise, but the entered textinputs just aren't visible and it's not due to styling :/

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your requirements.

Comment: thank you! the text is now visible but i can add only one item to the list, how can i add more? @TheAlpha93